# Webpack 2: Run a loader before plugins

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I want to run a loader before the plugins, especialy I want to run first handlebar-template-loader and after run a plugin that will parse the handlebar as javascript code.Alternatively I will happy if i could parse a module in a loader with the compiler parser.